# What is the intuition behind the Geometric Burrows-Wheeler Transform?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, data-compression, pattern-recognition

What is the intuition behind the [Geometric Burrows-Wheeler Transform](http://www.cs.nthu.edu.tw/~wkhon/papers/CHSV08.pdf)? And how can I use a GBWT with *blocking factor* $d$ to  match a given pattern $P$  of length $|P| = m$ with

- $m \ge d$
- $m < d$

What benefits does it have over the standard BWT used with backward search?